# Facebook Android SDK request parameters: where find documentation?

Tags: android, facebook, documentation, facebook-android-sdk

Good evening. 
I'm developing an android application that uses Facebook SDK.
I've no problem with user oauth authentication and I've no problem using the SDK to add a simple status update on the user wall.

Now I'm trying to use more deeply this Facebook Android SDK and I found a really big lack about documentation.

At the moment I'm using this snippet of code to add the user status:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "my message");
    params.putString("link", "my site url" );
    params.putString("name", "my name");
    params.putString("caption", "my caption" );

    mAsyncRunner.request(REQUEST_WALL_POST, params, HTTP_METHOD_POST, listener, null);
```

it works pretty well.

Now I want to add more content and attributes to this facebook status. For example (in my scenario) I want to add the user location (taken with Android GPS) to the facebook update.
I tried to search into Facebook API Documentation but the only "semi-usefull" thing I found is this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

For what I understand this explain which are a Post's return fields and not fields I can use to create a add-post request.

Anyway I found the "place" field:

> place
>
> Location associated with a Post, if any
>
> **object** containing **id** and **name** of Page associated with this location,
>   and a **location** field containing geographic information such as
>   **latitude**, **longitude**, **country**, and other fields (fields will vary based
>   on geography and availability of information)

I cannot find any kind of working example (or simple an example!!) to understand how to build this field and if I can or not pass to the Android bundle..

Can someone explain me?

**UPDATE**

I just made a share with SoundHound (a music application) and what I need is to perfeclty do something like it: https://www.facebook.com/emanuele.ricci/timeline/story?ut=64&wstart=1325404800&wend=1328083199&hash=-4777352490458351023

Exactly like it!

**UPDATE2**

This is the result: https://www.facebook.com/emanuele.ricci/timeline/story?ut=64&wstart=1325404800&wend=1328083199&hash=-1081865809871332449

Perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found something interesting.

This is the facebook documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall

What I need to use is this:

> **properties**
>
> A JSON object of key/value pairs which will appear in the
> stream attachment beneath the description, with each property on its
> own line. Keys must be strings, and values can be either strings or
> JSON objects with the keys text and href.

I will experiment a bit and I'll post some results :)