# Get friend list facebook 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to obtain my friend list from facebook using new SDK(3.0). I'm facing problems related to what kind of params I need to insert in a Bundle and how to use newMyFriendRequest and GraphAPI.

I didn't find on facebook documentation a place about what kind of field does we have to use. Based on [GraphExplorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I insert in my Bundle the key "fields" with this string "id,name,friend" as a value. The code below shows what I'm doing right now. After I get My picture and name I execute newMyFriendRequest. I believe it uses GraphAPI by default.

I've seen here on StackOverflow some posts related:

[How to send a FQL query with the new Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145284/how-to-send-a-fql-query-with-the-new-android-sdk)

[Facebook Android SDK request parameters: where find documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933104/facebook-android-sdk-request-parameters-where-find-documentation)

It helps me little and I don't want to use FQL. For response II'm receiving this JSON like an answer:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 100, errorType: FacebookApiException, errorMessage: Unsupported operation}, isFromCache:false}
```

Notice I'm very new in Facebook SDK for Android.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState sessionState, Exception ex){
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
        getUserData(session);
    }
}

private void getUserData(final Session session){
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if(user != null && session == Session.getActiveSession()){
                pictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                userName.setText(user.getName());
                getFriends();

            }
            if(response.getError() !=null){

            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}

private void getFriends(){
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(activeSession.getState().isOpened()){
        Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession, 
            new GraphUserListCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                        Response response) {
                    Log.i("INFO", response.toString());

                }
        });
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "id,name,friends");
        friendRequest.setParameters(params);
        friendRequest.executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not setting any params? The id and name are there by default, so you don't have to request them. I don't think "friends" is a valid field. Try removing the Bundle and the setParameters altogether, and just call friendRequest.executeAsync().

Comment: @MingLi Works fine with your observations. My intention is to get friendlist and profile image for each of them. For this, I believe I need to pass a parameter into a bundle. If this is true what param do I need to pass? See, facebook like I said is poor with this type of documentation.

Comment: then what you want is "id,name,picture" for the "fields" parameter. You can also go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to try out queries very quickly (in this case I used /me/friends?fields=id,name,picture).

Comment: @MingLi Ok, works very good.

Comment: Sounds you had solved your problem, may I ask how you modify your code to get it work ?

Answer (score 22):

In getFriends() method, change this line:

```
params.putString("fields", "id,name,friends");
```

by

```
params.putString("fields", "id, name, picture");
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the first name and last name of friends

Comment: Yes, add the fields: first_name and last_name to the query

Comment: @ignacio_gs how can i get email of my friend?

Comment: try using this may solve `params.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, picture");`

Answer (score 11):

**Using FQL Query**

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
        "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

Request request = new Request(session,
        "/fql",                         
        params,                         
        HttpMethod.GET,                 
        new Request.Callback(){       
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());

        try{
            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
            Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("uid",friend.getString("uid"));
                Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));
                Log.d("pic_square",friend.getString("pic_square"));             
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                  
}); 
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

**Ref** : [Run FQL Queries](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/)

Comment: hi! I just want to ask why this code only returns the facebook friends who are also give permission to the app? Why it doesn't return all facebook friends instead? Thanks

Comment: @JayR this is new Facebook's policy

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
// @Deprecated
// Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync()

// Use this instead:
Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new GraphUserListCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) 
    {
        if(response.getError() == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("users", "users " + users.get(i).getName());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                           response.getError().getErrorMessage(), 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @proGamer The replacement is to use `Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session, GraphUserListCallback)`, which returns a `Request` on which you can either call `executeAsync()` or `executeAndWait()`

Comment: @karl How will get the result of `executeAsync() or executeAndWait()` I mean which call back method is called as a result ?

Comment: @prateek Just like above - the `GraphUserListCallback` is the same as in Mohit Verma's answer. It receives the `onCompleted` call when the request completes, either with success or failure.

Comment: @Mohit Verma i m working on facebook with new facebook sdk but i dont get the friends list of mine. any idea about it?

Comment: This method has been deprecated and it only returns the friends that are using the App from where you are calling the API.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Facebook remove those permissions.

/me/friends returns the user's friends who are also using your app.

In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

In v1.0, it was possible to ask for permissions that would allow an app to see a limited amount of friend data, such as a person's friend's likes, their birthdays, and so on.

In v2.0, those permissions have all been removed. It's no longer possible for an app to see data from a person's friends unless those friends have also logged into the app and granted permission for the app to see it that data

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v2_0_friendlist_title

Answer (score 4):

You can use my code, you need to use the facebook library in your project. All the classes used for facebook are there in that sdk.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
                new GraphUserListCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                            Response response) {
                        Log.i("Response JSON", response.toString());
                        names = new String[users.size()];
                        id = new String[users.size()];
                        for (int i=0; i<users.size();i++){
                            names[i] = users.get(i).getName();
                            id[i]= users.get(i).getId();                                
                        }                           
                    }
                });
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

names and ids are two String arrays and now have all the names and ids of the friends. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Not working. It was deprecated and now it only returns the friends that are using the App from where you are calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

For the person ask how obtein the first name and the last name, you need put first_name and last_name instead of name.

```
params.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, picture");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code to get the friend list from Facebook. It will
>   show only  the data of those users who has been done Facebook login
>   with the app, and the users have Facebook id's on the database. then
>   this will show the list of those friends.

**FacebookFriendListActivity.java**

```
package com.application.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestBatch;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience;
import com.facebook.SessionLoginBehavior;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.internal.SessionTracker;
import com.facebook.internal.Utility;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import Info.InfoUsers;
import india.application.upflair.Adapter.FindPeopleAdapter;
import india.application.upflair.R;
import utills.ConnectionDetector;
import utills.Constant;

public class FacebookFriendListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    //facebook section
    SessionTracker mSessionTracker;
    Session mCurrentSession = null;

    String facebook_id;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);


        signInWithFacebook();


    }

    /***
     * facebook section to get friend list
     */
    private void signInWithFacebook() {
        mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(), new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                //TODO..
            }
        },
                null, false);

        String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getBaseContext());
        mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        mCurrentSession = session;

        if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(FacebookFriendListActivity.this);
            if (openRequest != null) {
                openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
                openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email", "user_location", "user_friends"));
                openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
                accessFacebookUserInfo();


            }
        } else {
            accessFacebookUserInfo();
        }
    }

    Request friendListRequest = null;
    private void accessFacebookUserInfo() {
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null & Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {



            Request cover_request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {}
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(cover_request);

            Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    try {

                        friendListRequest.executeAsync();

                    } catch (Exception jex) {
                        jex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch(meRequest);

            requestBatch.addCallback(new RequestBatch.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {}
            });
            requestBatch.executeAsync();

            friendListRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try {
                        GraphObject graphObj = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (graphObj != null) {

                            JSONObject jsonObj = graphObj.getInnerJSONObject();
                            JSONArray data=jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                            if(data.length()>0 && data!=null)
                            {
                                for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject dataobj= data.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String name=dataobj.getString("name");
                                    String id=dataobj.getString("id");

                                    System.out.println("name==============" + name);
                                    System.out.println("id==============" + id);

                                    facebooklist.add(id);

                                    facebook_id = facebooklist.toString().replace("[", "");
                                    facebook_id = facebook_id.replace("]", "");

                                }




                            }


                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {

                accessFacebookUserInfo();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "some thing went wrong plz try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "some thing went wrong plz try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mCurrentSession = null;
            mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        }
    }



}
```